# Add a StackPanel to a ComboBoxItem Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a windows program built on WPF. I am making it more customizable for the end user by utilizing an ini file. Currently I have a ComboBox with several items, and a StackPanel between sections of the ComboBox:

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="75,0,5,5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="50% Margin" />
            <Rectangle />
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Windows" Uid="0" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Gutters" Uid="0" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Insulation" Uid="0" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Doors" Uid="0" />
    <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="50% Margin, No Overage" />
            <Rectangle />
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Kitchens" Uid="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bathrooms" Uid="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Additions" Uid="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Basements" Uid="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="35% Margin" />
            <Rectangle />
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Siding" Uid="2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Roofing" Uid="2" />
</ComboBox>
```

How do I add the StackPanel inside of the ComboBox item programatically? Unfortunately for me, ComboBoxItem does not have a children property which would make this really easy.

Comment: `ComboBoxItem` has a `Content` property that should do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, I was under the impression that `Content` was restricted to text. I will give this a whirl and report back.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Would you mind posting your comment as a question so I can give you (proper) credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBoxItem` has a `Content` property that should do what you want.

In general if you want to know to which property the XAML content of an element is mapped to, walk up the **inheritance hierarchy** and look for the `[ContentPropertyAttribute]` attribute.

`ComboBoxItem` inherits from `ListBoxItem` which itself inherits from `ContentControl` which is "tagged" with `[ContentPropertyAttribute("Content")]`. :)